# Find and count from array in another array using linq C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, count

I have the following scenario:

I get a collection of records from a data source and add them to a List

```
List<Entity> e = new List<Entity>();
foreach (var elm in datasource)
{
      e.Add(new Entity { First = elm.First, Second = elm.Second, Third = elm.Third });
}
```

This gives me something like:

```
// -> First = John, Second = Sally, Third = Ingrid
// -> First = Sally, Second = Ingrid, Third = James
// -> First = Ingrid, Second = Sally, Third = James
```

I have an array of possible values that can be true and possible values that can be negative, in a List

```
List<string> positives = { "John", "Sally" }
List<string> negatives = { "Ingrid", "James" }
```

I am looking for an elegant why of matching the amount of positives and the amount of negatives I have in the generic list e, as per the above? Would something like this be possible with LINQ?

As I am not familiar with LINQ have no idea where to start. I tried something like:

```
var pos = e.SelectMany(s => s in positives).Count()
```

But this throws an exception.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

SQL's `in` clause in LINQ is `Contains` method.

Test:

```
var pos = e.SelectMany(s => positives.Contains(s)).Count();
```

Seems that I haven't understood your question. Reading again.

To be honest, your question in not well-phrased.
But based on what I understood, I think the correct response is:

```
var pos = e.SelectMany(i => positives.Contains(i.First) 
                            || positives.Contains(i.Second) 
                            || positives.Contains(i.Third)).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `in` incorrectly

```
e.SelectMany(s => positives.Contains(s)).Count();
```

but what I assue you are wanting is this

```
var pos = e.Count(s => positives.Contains(s.First) || positives.Contains(s.Second) ||positives.Contains(s.Third));

var neg= e.Count(s => negatives.Contains(s.First) || negatives.Contains(s.Second) ||negatives.Contains(s.Third));
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can use an any

```
var pos = e.SelectMany(i => 
    positives.Any(p=> p==i.First || p==i.Second || p==i.Third))
    .Count();
```